# multiFilter with MixItUp jQuery - separate control lists

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've got 4 elements and 3 sets of controls they need to be filtered through

**Controls**

```
<div class="controls">
<ul>
    <h4>Width</h4>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="Fixed Fluid">Either</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="Fixed">Fixed Width</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="Fluid">Fluid Width</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <h4>Columns</h4>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="1 2 3">Show All</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="1">1 Column</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="2">2 Column</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="3">3 Column</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <h4>Carousel</h4>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="Yes No">Both</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="No">No Carousel</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="Yes">Carousel</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Filters**

```
<ul id="Grid">
<li class="mix Fixed Yes 1"><h6>Item 1</h6></li>
<li class="mix Fixed No 2"><h6>Item 2</h6></li>
<li class="mix Fluid No 2"><h6>Item 3</h6></li>
<li class="mix Fluid No 1"><h6>Item 4</h6></li>
</ul>
```

**Function**

```
$(function(){
    $('#Grid').mixitup( {
        multiFilter: false,
        filterLogic: 'or',
        transitionSpeed: '600'
    });
});
```

Don't understand how to be able to select one item from each list and have it display filters that match that. Using the 'and' filterLogic causes even more issues as multiple controls in the same list can be selected. I'm lost and can't find any demos for this. Tips and suggestions?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheEks/AyDDq/1/)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly do you want to achive? Can you give an example of a desired behavior?